# Adding function to Oracle is not permament

Tags: oracle

I am experiencing weird behavior of Oracle Database 19c. I created user-defined function named raw_to_guid in SqlDeveloper for user 'TEST'. Content of this function is not important really because it's compiling successfully but just in case I share with code below.

```
create or replace function raw_to_guid( raw_guid in raw ) return varchar2
is
  hex varchar2(32);
begin

  hex := rawtohex(raw_guid);

  return substr(hex, 7, 2) 
      || substr(hex, 5, 2) 
      || substr(hex, 3, 2) 
      || substr(hex, 1, 2) 
      || '-'
      || substr(hex, 11, 2) 
      || substr(hex, 9, 2) 
      || '-'
      || substr(hex, 15, 2) 
      || substr(hex, 13, 2) 
      || '-'
      || substr(hex, 17, 4) 
      || '-'
      || substr(hex, 21, 12);

end
```

Next step is establish connection to Oracle database from my app and provide login data for user 'TEST'. I have several SELECT statements which use function raw_to_guid and all works perfectly fine.

Now is the clue of my problem:
For first 3-4 calls my SELECT statements works but then (during the same operations) Oracle returns an error `Package or function %s is in an invalid state`. Again I execute `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION raw_to_guid...` in SqlDeveloper and everything is working fine for short time but after few minutes the same exception occurs.
It seems like Oracle automatically drops my user-defined function and I do not understand why because I have not any `DROP FUNCTION` statement in my code.
The same problem occurs when I close database session in my app and create it again.

Is there a way to add this function permamently?

Comment: Are you sure it's that function it's complaining about? You said you have several queries and the first few work, so is a later one calling something else, instead of or as well as this function; perhaps the same function name in a different schema, for instance? You can query `user_objects` to look for invalid objects, or `user_errors` to see the problems - though only for things in your schema. You might find something in `all_errors` depending on privileges.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't dropped - you'd get a different error in that case. It is *invalidated*.  Why? No idea.

Here's an example which shows what *might* have happened (only if your code looked like this):

Procedure (you don't have):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test is
  2  begin
  3    null;
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.
```

Procedure is called from the function (line #5):

```
SQL> create or replace function raw_to_guid( raw_guid in raw ) return varchar2
  2  is
  3    hex varchar2(32);
  4  begin
  5    p_test;
  6    hex := rawtohex(raw_guid);
  7
  8    return substr(hex, 7, 2)
  9        || substr(hex, 5, 2)
 10        || substr(hex, 3, 2)
 11        || substr(hex, 1, 2)
 12        || '-'
 13        || substr(hex, 11, 2)
 14        || substr(hex, 9, 2)
 15        || '-'
 16        || substr(hex, 15, 2)
 17        || substr(hex, 13, 2)
 18        || '-'
 19        || substr(hex, 17, 4)
 20        || '-'
 21        || substr(hex, 21, 12);
 22
 23  end;
 24  /

Function created.
```

Does it work? Yes:

```
SQL> select raw_to_guid('abc') res from dual;

RES
----------
BC0A----

SQL>
```

But, if I drop the procedure, function - which references it - gets invalidated (error you got):

```
SQL> drop procedure p_test;

Procedure dropped.

SQL> select raw_to_guid('abc') res from dual;
select raw_to_guid('abc') res from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06575: Package or function RAW_TO_GUID is in an invalid state


SQL>
```

If I recreate the procedure, function recompiles automatically and everything is OK again:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test is
  2  begin
  3    null;
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> select raw_to_guid('abc') res from dual;

RES
----------
BC0A----

SQL>
```

---

Code you posted (if that's the whole code) probably doesn't suffer from that; `substr` and `rawtohex` certainly aren't dropped or were somehow invalidated so that it would cause your function to also be invalidated (as a collateral victim).

---

What to do? When it fails again, don't just *recreate* it - check what's wrong by querying `user_errors`. For example:

```
SQL> drop procedure p_test;

Procedure dropped.

SQL> select raw_to_guid('abc') res from dual;
select raw_to_guid('abc') res from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06575: Package or function RAW_TO_GUID is in an invalid state


SQL> select line, position, text from user_errors where name = 'RAW_TO_GUID';

      LINE   POSITION TEXT
---------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
         5          3 PLS-00201: identifier 'P_TEST' must be declared
         5          3 PL/SQL: Statement ignored

SQL>
```

Hopefully, you'll find the culprit.